# sizeof() applied to structure and variable

Tags: c, clang

consider the following snippet:

```
struct foo {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};

struct foo f;
printf("%u, %u\n", sizeof(struct foo), sizeof(f));
```

The code returns the same values, but I was wondering if sizeof() applied to variable is correct or this is just coincidence?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try Googling "sizeof applied to variable"? The first two results (one of which is from StackOverflow) would've been able to answer your question.

Comment: Yes, both `sizeof` expressions return the same value.  Note that the second one doesn't require parentheses; `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.  But `%u` requires an argument of type `unsigned int`, not `size_t`.  Write this: `printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof (struct foo), sizeof f);` or this: `printf("%lu %lu\n", (unsigned long)sizeof (struct foo), (unsigned long)sizeof f);`.  `%zu` is a C99-specific feature; your system's `printf` mignt not support it.

Answer (score 6):

Both will and should indeed return the same value.

From MSDN:

**The sizeof Operator**
The sizeof operator gives the amount of storage, in bytes, required to store an object of the type of the operand. This operator allows you to avoid specifying machine-dependent data sizes in your programs.

```
sizeof unary-expression  
sizeof ( type-name )
```

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof` works with *types* and *expressions*. When you apply it to a type, the `()` are part of `sizeof` syntax: `sizeof(type)`. When you apply it to an expression `()` are not part of `sizeof` syntax: `sizeof expression`.

So your second `sizeof` is not really "applied to a variable". It is applied to an expression `(f)`. That expression consists of a single variable `f` enclosed into a redundant pair of `()`. You could also do without that redundant pair of `()` and use just `sizeof f`.

When `sizeof` is applied to an expression, it returns the size of the expression result (i.e. the size of the type that expression has). In your example both applications of `sizeof` are guaranteed to evaluate to the same value.

In fact, a good programming practice is to avoid `sizeof(type)` as much as possible, i.e. prefer to use `sizeof expression`. This makes your code more type-independent, which is always a good thing. Type names belong in declarations and nowhere else.

Answer (score 1):

This is as expected, i.e. both will return the same value. This value is calculated at compile-time.

It's usually a good practice to use the variable in `sizeof` as you might later change the type and thus the size might change as well.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is preferable to apply it to the variable. It will then remain correct if the type of the variable changes.

Comment: The disadvantage of this way is that if you change variable's type from "just struct" to "pointer to struct", then sizeof(variable) will become 4 (or 8 depending on architecture) and compiler will happily accept it without saying you any warning.